# Insert special characters in java.util.Date type

Tags: java

In this `invprbm.setFollowUpDate()` is `java.util.Date` type.
If the given value is empty, I have to set `followUpDate` as special characters `- -`, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("- -");
invprbm.setFollowUpDate(formatter.parse("- -"));
```

In this scenario I am getting a value like `Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1970` instead of the expected `- -`.

Comment: If you can explain a bit more. what is given and what do you need.

Comment: what is your input and what do you want as output

Comment: The date parser will not do that. You can always check the date for null or invalid value and return the required String. If the date is a valid date then the date parser can parse it. 

All the things are not as complicated to solve as you are thinking

Comment: I don't think that the Date API caters for such things, you method could return a string representing the date. You could then check to see if it is the same as `- -` (later in your program) or not.

Comment: every time set value to the java.util.Date object only, if have got any null value then set as "- -". how?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how you should parse an "empty" date that you have denoted by the string "- -".  And the simple answer is that you don't parse it!

Instead do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); // or whatever
if (str.equals("- -")) {
    invprbm.setFollowupDate(null);
} else {
    invprbm.setFollowUpDate(formatter.parse(str));
}
```

And if you actually want to go from a Date to a String, you do it something like this:

```
if (date == null) {
    invprbm.setFollowupDate("- -");
} else {
    invprbm.setFollowUpDate(formatter.format(date));
}
```

---

The problem with your current approach is that `SimpleDateFormat` is not designed to cope with `null` Dates.  It can't parse a string to produce a `null` Date object, and it can't format a `null` Date object.

What your current code is actually doing is specifying a format that doesn't tell the parser how to extract any components of a date / time from the input string.  The `parse` method is returning a Date object whose `getTime()` value is zero.  This is not unreasonable, since what you are trying to do falls outside of the javadoc specification for the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but here invprbm.setFollowUpDate is java.util.Date object. Please solve this issue...
Thanking You

Comment: @NaveenKumar - if `invprbm.setFollowUpDate` is a setter for a Date, then the first alternative solves the problem.  (And if it doesn't, you need to explain the problem more clearly.)